# What's a quick way to turn on the torch?

Tags: settings, samsung-galaxy-ace-plus, camera-flash

In my accessibility settings on my Samsung Galaxy Ace Plus (GT-S7500), there is an "Assistive light" option that "Turn[s] on torch to see better". It activates the light on the back of the device.

Is there a way I can activate the light quickly without having to go through the accessibility settings?

ps: If someone could tag this with "torch" and possibly also "gt-s7500", that would be great.

Comment: Might one of the thousands of [torch apps on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=torch&c=apps) be a solution to your question? Alternatively, automation apps like [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) could be used to e.g. turn on the torch "on shake" or other defined events.

Comment: Thanks, @Izzy. I wondered if there might be something built in to Android, but I'll look for an app.

Comment: They are sometimes pre-installed (look into your drawer for an app named "Torch", the `torch.apk` file comes bundled e.g. with CyanogenMod in many cases -- might be it comes with stock as well). Some devices even offer it for the shortcut-bar integrated into the notification area.

Answer (score 1):

Theres a Torch app in the market that toggles on open.

Do you want a single button on home screen? Then you need to shortcut it.

Do you need it on your lock screen: swipe for widgets.

Do you need it on voice activation? "Ok google, open app flashlight/torch"

Do you want it on your shortcut bar? Drag it from programs.

Im not really sure what you want.

Comment: Was hoping I wouldn't have to install an app that loads up ads just so I can open the torch quicker. A toggle-on-open feature would be great. I'd most appreciate whichever option is the quickest and easiest to open (without activating in my pocket), starting with the lock screen active. Maybe a custom lock screen is the way to go...

Comment: Nexus torch doesnt have ads. At least mine doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few apps named "Nexus Torch" (as per the suggestion by @TardisGuy), but the one by Ben Buxton is nice and simple without having advertising or needing access to more than is sensible.

On my previous phone, the torch could be turned on through the Accessibility menu, but that option seems to have disappeared on my newer phone. Instead, I can select Apps, then select the Widgets tab, and there is an Assistive Light widget I could tap-and-hold then drag to create a shortcut for (the widget had some Asian letters on it, but the shortcut it created was in English).

Answer (score -1):

Try adding it as a Widget to your devices screen